# Failed to precompile build_runner:build_runner:

Tags: flutter, build-runner

I created a new project, added dependencies
when I launch it
flutter pub run build_runner build
I get:

```
/C:/Users/Michael/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-1.6.0/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:1600:40: Error: Getter not found: 'topLevelVariable'.
      return kinds.contains(TargetKind.topLevelVariable);
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Michael/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-1.6.0/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:2024:23: Error: Getter not found: 'topLevelVariable'.
      case TargetKind.topLevelVariable:
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Michael/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-1.6.0/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:2024:23: Error: Type 'dynamic' of the case expression is not a subtype of type 'TargetKind' of this switch
 expression.
 - 'TargetKind' is from 'package:meta/meta_meta.dart' ('/C:/Users/Michael/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.3.0/lib/meta_meta.dart').
      case TargetKind.topLevelVariable:
                      ^
/C:/Users/Michael/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-1.6.0/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:2001:13: Context: The switch expression is here.
    switch (this) {
            ^
pub finished with exit code 1
```

I've read everything on stackoverflow, but I haven't found a solution.
Any idea?

Comment: You can fix this using this [Error on flutter pub run build_runner build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67702879/16036745)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the analyzer version

```
analyzer: 1.5.0
```

Warning: do not up to the latest version, because it depends on `meta` package as is `flutter_test` - where you can't specify the version